# How can I combine two parametric plots in a continuous one?

Tags: plotting

I'm studying the [Ekman spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekman_spiral) for piecewise uniform viscosity. So I have two velocity components (u,v) for every layer. One pair for the surface and one pair for the layer below.

```
u1[z_] := A*Cos[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] - Exp[-z/ε]) + B*Sin[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] + Exp[-z/ε]) + u0*Exp[-z/ε] Cos[z/ε]

v1[z_] := A*Sin[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] + Exp[-z/ε]) - B*Cos[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] - Exp[-z/ε]) - u0*Exp[-z/ε] Sin[z/ε]

u2[z_] := Exp[z/(l*ε)] (K*Cos[z/(l*ε)] + L*Sin[z/(l*ε)])

v2[z_] := Exp[z/(l*ε)] (K*Sin[z/(l*ε)] - L*Cos[z/(l*ε)])
```

`A`, `B`, `K`, `L`, `l`, `u0` and ε`,` are constants that I change depending on the occasion I want to study:

```
A := (ε*(f1 + f2))/(2*r*k1) + u0
B := -(((ε*f2) + (u0*r*k1))/(2*r*k1))
K := 1/(2 k1 r) Exp^(h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)) ((2 k1 r u0 + (f1 + f2) ε) Cos[h(1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - Exp^((2 h)/ε) (f1 + f2) ε Cos[h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] - (k1 r u0 + f2 ε) (Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - Exp^((2 h)/ε) Sin[h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)]))
L := 1/(2 k1 r) Exp^(h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)) (-(k1 r u0 + f2 ε) Cos[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] + Exp^((2 h)/ε) (k1 r u0 + f2 ε) Cos[h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] - 2 k1 r u0 Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - f1 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - f2 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] + Exp^((2 h)/ε) f1 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] + Exp^((2 h)/ε) f2 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)])


f := 10^(-4)

u0 := 0.2

f1 := 0.43

f2 := 0.43

k1 := 10^(-2)

k2 := 10^(-3)

ε := Sqrt[2 k1/f]

l := Sqrt[k2/k1]

r := 1027

h := 2
```

I can plot every layer separately by using the `ParametricPlot` and `ParametricPlot3D` comands, for a specific depth and make two seperate spirals.

```
ParametricPlot[{u1[z], v1[z]}, {z, 0, -2}]
ParametricPlot[{u2[z], v2[z]}, {z, -2, -20}]
```

What I need to do now, is to merge my two seperate spirals into one spiral. Not to show two different spirals in the same graph though, but one combined spiral-a single curve, that will be built by using the first equations (u1,v1) untill a certain depth (0,-2m) and the other two (u2,v2) below that (-2,-20m). Like a plot of two parametric plots. And i need to show it both in 2D and 3D.

What I practicly have to observe is how the spiral is changing as you move through the layers of diferent viscosities. Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: `Graphics` can be combined using `Show`. For any additional advice, edit your question to include your code (InputForm) for a **minimal** example.

Comment: @BobHanlon First of all thank you for answring! I wasn't so clear probably. What I need to make is to merge my two seperate spirals into one spiral. Not two different spirals in the same graph but one combined spiral-a single curve, that will be using the first equations untill a certain depth and the other two below that. Like a plot of two parametric plots.

Comment: As stated previously, post code for a minimal example. It is still not clear that `Show` cannot do what is required. If not, perhaps `ConditionalExpression`. But without some minimal example we are just guessing -- and many will be unwilling to expend effort if they are just guessing at the problem.

Comment: @BobHanlon thank you for your advice, it's my first time here! Hope now it's more clear!

Comment: In order to plot your functions you need to provide the values for `{A, B, K, l, L, u0, \[CurlyEpsilon]}`. Questions should include minimal code and data required to produce results.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes I should have written that these values have been determined already. These are just constants that I change to study different occasions and results, that's why i didn't write them down. There's nothing more on my code than what I've already written, besides the constants and as I wrote i've already plot the spirals separately, I just need to merge them. I hope I gave you as much clues as I could, I'm trying to express myself the best way I can in english!

Comment: Your English is good.  You just shouldn't expect folks to guess what values of the parameters you might use.  Please put in a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f = 10^(-4);
u0 = 1/5;
f1 = 43/100;
f2 := 43/100;
k1 = 10^(-2);
k2 = 10^(-3);
ε = Sqrt[2 k1/f];
l = Sqrt[k2/k1];
r = 1027;
h = 2;

A = (ε*(f1 + f2))/(2*r*k1) + u0;

B = -(((ε*f2) + (u0*r*k1))/(2*r*k1)) // Simplify;
```

`Exp^z` is incorrect syntax and should be either `Exp[z]` or `E^z`

```
K = 1/(2 k1 r) E^(h (1/(l*ε) - 
         1/ε)) ((2 k1 r u0 + (f1 + f2) ε) Cos[
        h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - 
      E^((2 h)/ε) (f1 + f2) ε Cos[
        h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] - (k1 r u0 + 
         f2 ε) (Sin[
          h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - 
         E^((2 h)/ε) Sin[
           h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)])) // Simplify;

L = 1/(2 k1 r) E^(h (1/(l*ε) - 
         1/ε)) (-(k1 r u0 + f2 ε) Cos[
        h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] + 
      E^((2 h)/ε) (k1 r u0 + f2 ε) Cos[
        h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] - 
      2 k1 r u0 Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - 
      f1 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] - 
      f2 ε Sin[h (1/(l*ε) - 1/ε)] + 
      E^((2 h)/ε) f1 ε Sin[
        h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)] + 
      E^((2 h)/ε) f2 ε Sin[
        h (1/(l*ε) + 1/ε)]) // Simplify;

u1[z_] := 
 A*Cos[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] - Exp[-z/ε]) +
   B*Sin[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] + 
     Exp[-z/ε]) + 
  u0*Exp[-z/ε] Cos[z/ε]

v1[z_] := 
 A*Sin[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] + Exp[-z/ε]) -
   B*Cos[z/ε] (Exp[z/ε] - 
     Exp[-z/ε]) - 
  u0*Exp[-z/ε] Sin[z/ε]

u2[z_] := 
 Exp[z/(l*ε)] (K*Cos[z/(l*ε)] + 
    L*Sin[z/(l*ε)])

v2[z_] := 
 Exp[z/(l*ε)] (K*Sin[z/(l*ε)] - 
    L*Cos[z/(l*ε)])
```

Using [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[{u1[z], v1[z]}, {z, 0, -2}],
 ParametricPlot[{u2[z], v2[z]}, {z, -2, -20}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to define a single function

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Piecewise[{
    {{u1[z], v1[z]}, -2 <= z <= 0},
    {{u2[z], v2[z]}, -20 <= z < -2}}], {z, -20, 0},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotRange -> All,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-20, 0}},
   LegendLabel -> Style[z, 14, Bold]]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the parameters use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

Comment: If you set `Exclusions -> None` in the `Piecewise` solution, it generate a single line. Not particularly important in the OP's apparent application, but the purist in me would like a continuous function represented by a continuous `Line[]`. :)